# How can i connect from windows xp to Sql Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-xp, sql-server-2017, windows-xp-sp3

We have some xp (very old) machines that can't connect to sql server 2017 (runs on Linux). We try to test connection with ODBC. The problem has to do with SSL.

Is there a way to turn it off, so it can work?

```
Error Message : Microsoft SQL Server Login
Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 772
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen(SECDoClientHandshake()).
Connection failed:
SQLSTATE: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 18
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error
```

Comment: Tested with SqlServer 2017 in both Windows and Linux

Comment: XP Machines are in SP3

Comment: Did you try turning off any encryption related options in the ODBC connection string?

Comment: I don't know and i don't think there is an encryption option. Do you know any?

Comment: Our purpose is to connect from an .net app. This is not possible ether.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and got the solution on https://www.smartftp.com/pt-br/support/kb/2754. Here are the steps, in the case this link goes south.

The solution involves adding support for TLS 1.2 on XP, available for "Windows Embedded POSReady 2009", which is based on Windows XP SP3 (more info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded_Industry#Windows_Embedded_POSReady_2009).

To make it work on "plain old XP", you'll need to add the following to the Windows Registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\WPA\PosReady] 
"Installed"=dword:00000001
```

Next, the registry entries for TLS:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

Next is to get the needed update at Microsoft, KB4019276 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows). Install the update and reboot.